# How does Tensorflow's Decision Forests handle categorical data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, decision-tree, unsupervised-learning

I'm evaluating two different unsupervised ML algorithms, Isolation Forest and LSTM Autoencoder model, to identify anomalies in a large time series data. This dataset includes mostly categorical data such as Ip Adresses, cloud subscription Ids,tenant Ids, userAgents, and client Application Ids.

When reading a [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/decision_forests/tutorials/beginner_colab) on an implementation of a Tensorflow's Decision Tree (TF-DF) model, it mentions that the model handles non-label categorical values natively and

> **there is no need for preprocessing in the form of one-hot encoding, normalization or extra is_present feature.**

Does anybody know how Tensorflow handles the categorical features behind the scenes (assuming they do some transformation into a numeric representation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tl;dr**: *There is a natural way of using categorical features in decision trees/forests that requires no encoding. Tensorflow Decision Forests uses this and a number of standard transformations to handle categorical features.*

Tensorflow Decision Forest (TF-DF) constructs decision tree / decision forest models. A single decision tree recursively splits the dataset along its features. Splits along categorical features  can naturally be performed through so-called *in-set conditions*. For instance, a tree can express a condition like `userAgents \in \{“Mozilla/5.0”, “InternetExplorer/10.0”\}`. Other types of conditions are [also possible](https://ydf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hyper_parameters.html#id5). Tensorflow Decision Forests (TF-DF) can construct in-set conditions if the dataset contains categorical features.

More specifically, Tensorflow Decision Forests uses the C++ library [Yggdrasil Decision Forests](https://ydf.readthedocs.io) (YDF) under the hood for any advanced computations. YDF offers [three different algorithms](https://ydf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hyper_parameters.html#id5) for finding a good categorical split of the data. For example, the `Random` algorithm will just try out many possible splits at random and pick the best one.

For performance and quality reasons, YDF also preprocesses categorical features: If a categorical value is very rare, YDF may consider it “out-of-dictionary”, the threshold for “rare” being [user-configurable](https://github.com/google/yggdrasil-decision-forests/blob/caf07f9114f4b91cf19635975ed1292ab1de99c6/yggdrasil_decision_forests/dataset/data_spec.proto#L128-L135). Furthermore, YDF maps the categorical features to integers by decreasing item frequency, with the mapping stored as part of the model. Note that this is purely an internal encoding; the algorithms are aware that a feature is categorical, hence typical issues with integer encodings do not apply.

Finally, Tensorflow Decision Forests (TF-DF) uses Keras, which expects classification tasks to have an integer label. Therefore, TF-DF users have to encode the label themselves or use the built-in [pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/decision_forests/tutorials/beginner_colab#:%7E:text=Labels%20are%20a%20bit%20different%3A%20Keras%20metrics%20expect%20integers.%20The%20label%20(species)%20is%20stored%20as%20a%20string%2C%20so%20let%27s%20convert%20it%20into%20an%20integer.).

Note that this answer only applies to Tensorflow Decision Forests. Other parts of Tensorflow may need manual encoding.